# Prove if a number is always negative or positive.

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

Consider four positive numbers $x_1 ,x_2,y_1$ and $y_2$  such that $y_1y_2 > x_1x_2$  .
Consider the number $ S = (x
_1y_2 + x_2y_1 ) − 2x_1x_2$ . The number S is
(A) always a negative integer;
(B) can be a negative fraction;
(C) always a positive number;
(D) none of these.

Any hint on how to go about this will be appreciated.

Comment: Are the numbers naturals ?

Comment: Sorry, nothing about that is mentioned in the question. All number's are positive, but we can't say if they can be 0 as well.

Comment: I am querying about restriction to integers !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we have by $AM_GM$ $$\frac{x_1y_2+x_2y_1}{2}\geq \sqrt{y_1y_2x_1x_2}$$
since we have $$y_1y_2>x_1x_2$$ we get $$x_1x_2y_1y_2>(x_1x_2)^2$$ thus we get
$$\frac{x_1y_2+x_2y_1}{2}\geq \sqrt{x_1x_2y_1y_2}>\sqrt{(x_1x_2)^2}=x_1x_2$$ thus we have
$$x_1y_2+x_2y_1-2x_1x_2>0$$

Answer (score 2):

We have: $S \ge 2\sqrt{x_1x_2y_1y_2} - 2x_1x_2 > 0$ by AM-GM inequality.